# How to fix the 'undeclared type IKImageView' error in swift

Tags: swift, xcode6-beta6

This is the error message

[image]

I have imported `Foundation` but it did not fix the problem. What import am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IKImageView` class is in Quartz.framework . Add this framework to your project and Import this framework  `import Quartz`.

Answer (score 2):

#### every class's documentation has the info 'Framework' which tells you what you need

so from the docs for this class, it is:
"System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/ImageKit.framework"

1. link against the top framework - Quartz
2. import it

Comment: Thanks! I really didn't know about this before!